# Unity C# new byte[Marshal.SizeOf(typeof())] Crash

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Now send or send the C # structure array to TCP.
The problem occurs when converting to byte [] buffer conflicts with Unity.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]

public struct GameRoomInfo{
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
public int GameRoomNum;
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
public int[] UID;
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
public int[] CharacterType;
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
public float[] Position_X;
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
public float[] Position_Y;
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
public float[] Position_Z;
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
public float[] Rotation_X;
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
public float[] Rotation_Y;
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
public float[] Rotation_Z;

   public GameRoomInfo(int[] _UID, int[] _CharacterType, float[] _px, float[] _py, float[] _pz, float[] _rx, float[] _ry, float[] _rz)
{
    GameRoomNum = 0;
    UID = _UID;
    CharacterType = _CharacterType;
    Position_X = _px;
    Position_Y = _py;
    Position_Z = _pz;
    Rotation_X = _rx;
    Rotation_Y = _ry;
    Rotation_Z = _rz;
}

public byte[] Serialize()
{
    var buffer = new byte[Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(GameRoomInfo))];
    var gch = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    var pBuffer = gch.AddrOfPinnedObject();

    Marshal.StructureToPtr(this, pBuffer, false);
    gch.Free();

    return buffer;
}

public void Deserialize(ref byte[] data)
{
    var gch = GCHandle.Alloc(data, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    this = (GameRoomInfo)Marshal.PtrToStructure(gch.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(GameRoomInfo));
    gch.Free();
}}
```

In Serialize () var buffer1 = new byte [Marshal.SizeOf (typeof (GameRoomInfo))] This part causes Unity 3d Crash.

Removing the int [] <--- Array removes the problem.

Am I misusing arrays of structures?

Help

Comment: How do you want the UID and CharacterType to be serialized? If the array length is not fixed as in the other arrays, you need to somehow also transport the length information.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. If you put SizeConst, it will still generate a crash in Unity.

Comment: So you changed `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]`to  `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType=UnmanagedType.I4, SizeConst = 16)]`?

Comment: UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.I <- This is now treated as.

If you use the wrong type, Unity sends a crash.

Thank you very much for your feedback.

Best wishes for a Happy New Year